# Teleporting Castle

Tags: story-identification

I remember seeing a movie when I was younger, but can't find it online because I can't remember a whole lot about the story.  What I do remember is there was a group of soldiers trying to catch this castle that appeared only during the day and at the start of each new day it would teleport to a new random location.  I also remember the main character having this neat little flying blade disk that reminds me of something from the *Predator* movies that he could control with his mind.  Again I can't recall a lot about the movie, but if it sounds familiar I would be grateful.  Also it seems like at one point there were horses that ran so fast they caught fire!

Comment: Do you remember roughly when this movie came out?

Comment: I remember it looking old when I was a kid in the 90s so i would guess mid to early 80s.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

The movie you are looking for is [Krull](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Krull_%28film%29).

> Prince Colwyn is found and nursed by Ynyr, the Old One. Ynyr tells him the Beast can be defeated with the "Glaive", an ancient, magical, five-pointed throwing weapon. Colwyn retrieves the Glaive from a high mountain cave before setting out to track down the Black Fortress, which teleports to a new location every day at sunrise. As they travel, Colwyn and Ynyr are joined by magician Ergo "the Magnificent" and a band of nine thieves, fighters, bandits and brawlers. Colwyn offers to clear their criminal records, successfully enlisting Torquil, Kegan, Rhun, Oswyn, Bardolph, Menno, Darro, Nennog, and Quain. The cyclops Rell later joins the group.

....

> The Fire Mares, steeds that travel so fast they leave a trail of flame and can effectively fly, are played by Clydesdale horses.

Comment: That's the one! Thank you. Just wondering is it one of those movies that as a kid seemed great and you shouldn't watch again as an adult because it will ruin it or is it worth another watch?

Comment: Well, it wasn't exactly one of the "great, classic" movies. Perhaps watching it without any particular expectations, you might find it fun.

Comment: When I saw Krull as a teen at the height of the Dungeons & Dragons craze (ok, D&D is still popular) I thought it was a thrilling adventure. Sure, the plot wasn't terribly complex or original. And compared with modern fantasy flicks the special effects are dated, some of the sets were clearly sets, and the action scenes could be a little goofy. But the spectacular film score by James Horner and the awesome scenery (filming locations in the Italian Alps) more than made up for the early 80s cheesiness.

Comment: Aside from the two so-so leads, there were solid English/Irish actors in the movie (including a young Liam Neeson!) that gave the movie some heft. And the Slayers were downright creepy - the scene when they emerge from the swamp still gives me the goosebumps. "SLAYERS!"

Comment: I've been meaning to rewatch that one for a while. Krull is awesome! It's even more awesome when you're really, really tired and hypercaffeinated.

Comment: They really need to remake Krull...and the minute I saw this question I knew it had to be Krull lol. The Glaive also makes a cameo appearance in the movie "Ready Player One."

Answer (score 8):

As you have already indicated by accepting [Donald.McLean's answer](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/63769/19561), the movie you were looking for is *[Krull](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Krull_%28film%29)*, a British-American fantasy/science fiction movie from 1983. Liam Neeson [plays a minor role](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0085811/fullcredits).

The bad guys travel the galaxy in a mountain-like spaceship called The Black Fortress, which teleports to a new location every sunrise. The heroes ride Fire Mares, horses so fast they leave a trail of flames in an attempt to catch up with it.

The 'neat flying blade disk' is called a (or perhaps 'the') Glaive and  can be seen on what appears to be the DVD cover.

[image: DVD cover Krull]

Comment: Since we [had a discussion](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/198/conversation/storyidanswers) in chat yesterday about what constitutes a good [tag:story-identification] answer, I decided to try and write one. It's _Community Wiki_, so I get no rep from it.

Comment: A much better answer. You have my upvote