# Looking for a movie from my childhood

Tags: story-identification, movie

I once saw a movie(sci-fi/fantasy) that I can't remember, but I know I liked it. I was really small and can't get any of the plot back together, but it was fairly old-ish movie (my guess would be 70's ~ 90's).

The only clues I remember are:

1. Hairy legged horses (like furry legs)
2. Star-like metal weapon that appeared multiple times
3. Group of people going from A to B, looking for something
4. One of the heros was a cyclops that died during the film by being squeezed between rocks
5. It wasn't animated.

If it rings any bell to anybody it would mean the world to me. Thanks a lot!

**EDIT:**

Somebody marked my question as duplicate of [this one](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/63768/teleporting-castle). While it points towards the same answer, the question was different. I didn't remember any teleporting castle and therefore my question wasn't answerable simply by using search.

Comment: Could it be [Krull](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Krull_(film))?

Comment: Did it seem to be aimed at kids? Roughly when did you watch it?

Comment: @SeanDuggan even though that question has also Krull as an answer, the wording structure of the question and the clues are completely different. If I searched with my clues all over the website, this question wouldn't have popped up, I'm afraid.

Comment: @Michal all the more reason to mark it a duplicate so that the next person to go searching can have twice as much information to compare when determining if it is the movie _they_ are thinking of.

Comment: @MatthewGreen Linked for that reason absolutely yes, but duplicate may lead to deletion no?

Comment: @Michal No duplicates don't get deleted. They are more like signposts. They only get deleted if they meet the usual requirements which this question is way past. http://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/duplicates

Comment: The presence of the multi-armed throwing weapon, the Glaive, is the big matching criteria for Krull to me. It's what almost everyone remembers. And yes, the system for marking Duplicates doesn't always make sense at first. The fundamental criteria isn't the question, but the answer.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This could be the 1983 live-action movie [Krull](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Krull_(film)) - which includes:

- the Glaive, "an ancient, magical, five-pointed throwing weapon";
- a series of journeys, with the ultimate goal of reaching the Black Fortress;
- a cyclops (called Rell), who "sacrifices himself to hold open the huge spaceship doors long enough to allow the others to enter".

Comment: Definitely this.

Comment: YES! Thank you!

Comment: @Michal: you're welcome!

Comment: Krull had a space ship?? That's one wild 80s "fantasy" movie, I just remember it being slow, like s-l-o-w slow